# Adding New Tab in PHP

Tags: php, menu, tabs, elgg

I am using **Menu Builder for Elgg 1.8** in my ELGG application to add new tab to my existing menu, but I'm not able to add.

I have menu with 9 tabs, now i'm trying to add new tab with url other than **[wwwroot]abc/**, say www.exampl.com, but i'm not able to add new tab, if I do so, it will overiding the existing tabs or not adding at all, but i'm getting successfully saved message.

Please help me to come out of this.

Comment: Yes, it's possible that Menu Builder does not support adding tabs (if that's your question) but perhaps you haven't written the appropriate code to so...

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Is there any file where i can set the maximum number of tabs, because I searched, I didn't find any configuration files to set count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you are trying to add complete URL in your new tab.

If you want to add a URL `www.exaple.com/abc` add like this URL `[wwwroot]abc/`

I also faced issue same as this, it resolved by using above method